# How to install specified Terraform version and use it further

Tags: terraform, microservices, homebrew

If I install Terraform via `brew install terraform@0.12` , it installed latest version `0.12.31`.

And then to use it I run command `alias terraform=$(brew config | awk '/HOMEBREW_PREFIX:/ { print $2 }')/opt/terraform@0.12/bin/terraform`.

But I need to use not the latest version, I want to use `0.12.29`.

And I can install it via

```
brew install tfenv
tfenv install 0.12.29
tfenv use 0.12.29
```

But I don't know how to specify this version ( `0.12.29` ) in `alias terraform=`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of this project? https://tfswitch.warrensbox.com/Quick-Start/
It makes adjusting the current version of terraform a lot easier.

Same for terragrunt https://warrensbox.github.io/tgswitch/additional.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).